# Exclude a div which is nested under another div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to exclude a div which is nested another div in jQuery. Following is my code,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".intro").not(".big").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
    <div class="intro">My name is Donald.
      <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
      <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
      <div class="big">Who is your favourite:</div>
    </div>
    <ul id="choose">
      <li>Goofy</li>
      <li>Mickey</li>
      <li>Pluto</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried `.not` and `.filter` methods, but they aren't working. I want to select `intro` class without selecting `big` class.

Comment: your query is only selecting one div: The one with class 'intro'

Comment: CSS only solution - .intro {background: yellow;} .big{background: white}

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".intro div:not(.big)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `not` on the children of `.intro` -

`$(".intro *").not(".big")`

BTW, if all you want is to change the background, you can do it by css -

```
.intro *:not('.big') {
    backgroung: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is working. But the `div` is positioned within the parent.

Why not set `.big` to `background-color: white;`?

Answer (score 0):

I would clone the original, then delete `.big` from the clone. Then you can do whatever you want with the clone.

```
var intro_copy = $('.intro').clone();
intro_copy.find('.big').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div intro is a wrapping the div big so when you apply a background colour to the intro class it will apply to the whole block hence you don't see the results. However, this can be achieved using just CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".intro").not(".big").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.big{background-color: white}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
    <div class="intro">My name is Donald.
      <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
      <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
      <div class="big">Who is your favourite:</div>
    </div>
    <ul id="choose">
      <li>Goofy</li>
      <li>Mickey</li>
      <li>Pluto</li>
    </ul>
```